# Column-layout tabular in subfigure

Tags: tables, positioning, subfloats

I want a table over each column in my figure that contains subfigures in a column-layout.
I have tried different combinations of minipage and adjustbox, but have not managed to find a solution.

The two tables should be next to each other, thus not having a y-offset.

[image: What it looks like right now]
My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[abs]{overpic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}

        \adjustbox{valign=t}{
                \subfloat{
                    \begin{tabular}{ll}
                        Line style      &       Explanation     \\  
                        \hline
                        some text 1 &       other text 1    \\
                        some text 2 &       other text 2    \\
                    \end{tabular}
                } \qquad
        } \qquad

        \adjustbox{valign=t,center}{
                \subfloat{
                    \begin{tabular}{ll}
                        Line style      &       Explanation     \\  
                        \hline
                        some text 1 &       other text 1    \\
                        some text 2 &       other text 2    \\
                    \end{tabular}
                } \qquad
        } 

    \end{minipage} \qquad


    \subfloat[\SI{30}{\degree} left]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\qquad
    \subfloat[\SI{30}{\degree} right]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\qquad
    \caption{figure name}
    \label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inserting several unwanted spaces and newlines. Don't use blank lines if you do not want new paragraphs to start.

```
\adjustbox{valign=t}{
    \subfloat{
```

has to be

```
\adjustbox{valign=t}{%
    \subfloat{%
```

because both lines introduce a spurious white space. It helps a lot if you load the package `lua-visual-debug` and compile with LuaLaTeX. You will see that your example is having many problems talking about margins and exaggerated boxes.

As I do not know, what you want to obtain by those `adjustbox`es, I took the liberty to rewrite your code as I would have written it. I hope, I got your right. Please note that there is just one blank line which is actually needed. You may want to change the width of those subfigures and tables. Instead of `\hfil` you can use `\hfill` if you want to push the boxes to the most outer position.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subtable}{.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            Line style  & Explanation  \\\midrule
            some text 1 & other text 1 \\
            some text 2 & other text 2 \\
        \end{tabular}\hfil
    \end{subtable}  
    \begin{subtable}{.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            Line style  & Explanation  \\\midrule
            some text 1 & other text 1 \\
            some text 2 & other text 2 \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}

    \begin{subfigure}{.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{\ang{30} left}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{\ang{30} right}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{figure name}\label{fig:label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you do not use any caption for your tables, you can also just put them in the same `subfigure` as your image which will result in much shorter code:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            Line style  & Explanation  \\\midrule
            some text 1 & other text 1 \\
            some text 2 & other text 2 \\
        \end{tabular}
        \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{\ang{30} left}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            Line style  & Explanation  \\\midrule
            some text 1 & other text 1 \\
            some text 2 & other text 2 \\
        \end{tabular}
        \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{\ang{30} right}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{figure name}\label{fig:label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. i did not know that blank lines are bad, as up until now I was using them to structure things.